# javascript and svg contour plots

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to make like this with javascript and svg ( they use pyhthon ):
[image]

I got the image from this site : [100-500hPa](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/HILO_Symbol_Plot.html)
From this site  :"
**MSLP and 1000-500 hPa Thickness with High and Low Symbols**
Plot MSLP, calculate and plot 1000-500 hPa thickness, and plot H and L markers. Beyond just plotting a few variables, in the example we use functionality from the scipy module to find local maximum and minimimum values within the MSLP field in order to plot symbols at those locations.
"

Here, equal pressure values ​​are drawn and low and high pressure centers are determined. They are written in Python language. I want to do this using javascript and svg.

I tried some codes ; didn't work.

Comment: maybe this would help: https://github.com/d3/d3-contour

Comment: you can show an example ?